# Getting column value based on other multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
 cid    si
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
```

I need to have another column with named ide which should add the same value until next 1 in si is encountered and value in cid remains same. If value in cid gets changed the identifier starts over. Adding sample output.

```
cid si  ide
A   1   aa
A   0   aa
A   1   bb
A   0   bb
A   1   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
A   0   cc
B   1   aa
B   0   aa
B   0   aa
B   0   aa
B   0   aa
B   0   aa
B   0   aa
```

Comment: Why does it start with `aa`? Where do we pull those values from?

Comment: most likely poor choice of words, also what's the rule to increase the values? from a to z and back to a then?

Comment: it is basically an identifier that new series has been started for "A" as soon as "1" occurs. it could be anything.

Comment: so it doesn't have to be aa, bb , cc, etc? just a counter of the group?

Comment: Yes. But should stay same until next occurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a mapping dictionary that maps 1...n with your desired filler values; here is a small example:

```
dct = {1: 'aa', 2: 'bb', 3: 'cc'}
```

Then use **`groupby`**, **`cumsum`** and **`map`**:

```
df.groupby('cid').si.cumsum().map(dct)
```

```
0     aa
1     aa
2     bb
3     bb
4     cc
5     cc
6     cc
7     cc
8     cc
9     cc
10    cc
11    cc
12    cc
13    cc
14    aa
15    aa
16    aa
17    aa
18    aa
19    aa
20    aa
Name: si, dtype: object
```

The important part here is **`cumsum`**, as that is how we know that a new group is starting:

```
df.groupby('cid').si.cumsum()
```

```
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    1
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
Name: si, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful